# Problem when connecting Django and Flutter websockets

Tags: django, flutter, websocket, chat

I'm trying to establish a connection with my Django backend and Flutter code using `WebSockets`, but unfortunately I'm unable to do so, went through many articles and videos and everyone is basically doing the same without receiving an error.. Please give a little push to, I'm kinda new into this.

First of all I created a new django app called 'chat_app' (added it into settings.py), where I created a new model of my `Messages`:

```py
    class Message(models.Model):
        room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        content = models.TextField()
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.content
```

Then I made my `consumers.py` (here I'm a little bit confused, isn't it better to refer to my room `unique_id` instead of name, since the ID is unique and not the name in my case? Decided to stick with the tutorial.)

```py
    class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
        def connect(self):
            self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
            self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
    
            # Join room group
            self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )
    
            self.accept()
    
        def disconnect(self, close_code):
            # Leave room group
            self.channel_layer.group_discard(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )
```

Done the `routing.py`

```py
    # The WebSocket URL pattern for chat rooms is defined by this code
    websocket_urlpatterns = [
        re_path(r'ws/chat_app/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
    ]
```

Then added it into my project URLs:

```py
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        ...,
        path('ws/', include(websocket_urlpatterns)),
    ]
```

And this is how I'm trying to establish a connection in Flutter, basically it is a new page, where I'm passing room data through the `Navigator` from the previous page:

```
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.room,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final RoomModelResponse room;

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final List<String> _messages = [];
  late WebSocketChannel _channel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
        'wss://192.168.0.11:8000/ws/chat_app/${widget.room.roomName}/'); // Update the WebSocket URL with your Django server address and room name
    _channel.stream.listen((message) {
      setState(() {
        _messages.add(message);
      });
    });
  }
```

**Outputs:**

In the flutter terminal I get the following message:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://192.168.0.11:8000/ws/chat_app/3wVCio/#' was not upgraded to websocket
#0      new IOWebSocketChannel._withoutSocket.<anonymous closure> (package:web_socket_channel/io.dart:119:24)
#1      Stream.handleError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:931:16)
#2      _HandleErrorStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:269:17)
#3      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
#4      _RootZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1606:10)
#5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:358:15)
#6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:7)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:280:7)
#8      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:788:19)
#9 <…>
```

Django:

```
Not Found: /ws/chat_app/3wVCio/
[15/Feb/2024 16:46:19] "GET /ws/chat_app/3wVCio/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4379
```

Where the "3wVCio" is the `unique_id` of my room.

I will provide additional information if need

**Update:**
The latest think I've tried is allowing all origin `CORS` in my project:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other installed apps
    'corsheaders',
]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

Unfortunately, no success..

Made my `ALLOWED_HOST` in Django settings to be equal to `['*']` and configured my `asgi.py` file as follows:

```py
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
    
    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        "http": get_asgi_application(),  # Django HTTP ASGI application
        "websocket": OriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(
                URLRouter(
                    websocket_urlpatterns
                ),
                ['*']
            )
        ),  # Django Channels WebSocket ASGI application
    })
```

I tried to handshake with the WebSocket using postman, here is the output:

```
Error: Unexpected server response: 404
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://192.168.0.11:8000/ws/chat_app/3wVCio/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: GW/3ZvtVDOXDlKNkIwg2zw==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: 192.168.0.11:8000
Response Headers
Date: Fri, 16 Feb 2024 15:28:45 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.12.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 4379
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me:

1. I have installed redis using `brew` - `brew install redis`
2. I have started redis, before starting my Django project - `redis-server`
   I'm not redis expert, please refer to [official redis website](https://redis.io/docs/install/install-redis/install-redis-on-mac-os/)
3. I have installed `daphne` `pip install daphne` and added it into my `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py:

```py
    # Application definition
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'daphne',
        ...,
    ]
```

4. I have added `ASGI_APPLICATION` in `settings.py` and configured my `asgi.py`.
   In `settings.py`:

```py
    ASGI_APPLICATION = 'project.asgi.application'
```

5. In `asgi.py`:

```py
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
    
    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
                URLRouter(
                    websocket_urlpatterns
                ),
            )
        })
```

6. I have added `CHANNEL_LAYERS` like so in `settings.py`:

```py
    # Configure channel layers
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
    },
    'ROUTING': 'ws.routing.application',
}
```

And with that, I have finally managed to connect "HANDSHAKE" and "CONNECT" with the WebSocket. I'm sorry, that I cannot give explanation why all of these worked. I just wanted to show, what worked for me.

> WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat_app/FxmZiA/ [192.168.0.11:60081]

> WebSocket CONNECT /ws/chat_app/FxmZiA/ [192.168.0.11:60081]

Answer (score 0):

in your `ChatScreen` file there is URL which is quite unusual because there suppose to be only one protocol either `wss` or `http` but you are using both so that might be the issue.
if you want to use web socket then protocol suppose to be only `wss or ws`.

Comment: yeah my bad, I have edited that in my code but forgot to upload it as a question. However, I still get an error let me post that

Comment: try check the api first in the postman or something that is it working or not.

Comment: the API itself is working, but when I try to handshake with the WebSocket it is not.. I tried it with postman, I will update the question